# One trivia on Miller Modigliani Theorem regarding the No arbitrage Argument

Tags: finance

Suppose there are a levered firm with firm value $V_L=D_L+E_L$ and an unlevered firm $V_U = E_U$ both yielding an income of $X$ at time 1. One direction of the no arbitrage argument goes like this: someone with $s$ shares of a levered firm equity can replicate her payoff by longing $s$ shares of unlevered firm and borrow $s D_L$ amount of debt. At time $1$, both positions will yield $s * \text{max}\{0, X-(1+r)D_L\}$, so value of the two positions should have the same value at time 0, giving $s E_L = s (V_L - D_L) = s(V_U-D_L)$, therefore $V_U = V_L$.

My confusion is with regard to the replicating position payoff. Shouldn't borrowing makes the replicating position unlimited liable? In particular, shouldn't the payoff of the replicating position be $s * \text{max}\{0, X\}-(1+r)D_L$? So if X ends up lower than $(1+r)D_L$, she is liable to still pay the difference for borrowing. While if she is holding an equity position in levered firm, her payoff is 0.